# Hijri Date Inserting to the Database

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, gregorian-calendar, hijri

In my database, I used gregorian Date. I want to insert hijri date. How can it be done or is there any problem with it. I used hibernate and JPA.

e.g. 2/30/1433 is hijri date. However, february is at most 29 days. In that case, is  there any error?

best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the best is convert hijri to gregorian. It is not important to convert correctly, if it can be reconvert to same hijri date.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL stores only Gregorian calendar dates for the modern period in the `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` objects. See [the documentation for date/time types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) which states:

> Dates are counted according to the Gregorian calendar, even in years
>   before that calendar was introduced (see Section B.4 for more
>   information).

For pre-Gregorian dates see [B.4 datetime units history](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datetime-units-history.html). [this mailing list thread](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Date-Time-Types-internals-td5649945.html) may also be useful.

If you want support for calendars other than the Gregorian calendar you need to find a PostgreSQL extension that understands the desired calendar or you need to store the dates as plain `text` strings in the DB.